# If element contains any of these words then wrap that word in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains, keyword

I'd like to highlight certain words if they're found within a title by wrapping those words in a span class. Is there a way of writing a list of words to check for and then using the same command to wrap any of those words with the span class?

For example:

```
<h1>This title contains the word Balloon</h1>
<h1>This title contains the word Oranges</h1>
<h1>This title doesn't contain either of those terms</h1>
```

Something to check each of those three elements (but there would be 20 or so) for the words Balloon or Oranges and then wrap just those words in a span color.

I could use:

```
$('h1').html($('h1').html().replace(/(balloon)/g,'<span class="red">balloon</span>'));
```

but I'd have to write that query for every word, whereas I'd like something a little simpler, if possible.

Comment: Note that the other problem with your example using `html` is that if you do that, you wipe out and recreate the elements, losing any event handlers or other state they have.

Comment: Use `$('h1').html(function(){})`

Comment: How about creating an array with the words you want to check and then loop through them with the snippet you posted?

Comment: Have a look at https://markjs.io

Comment: Define what you mean by word? Any substring or boundary ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery search in static HTML page with highlighting of found word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011385/jquery-search-in-static-html-page-with-highlighting-of-found-word)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep an array of words, then iterate and replace the words in each header

```js
var words = [
    "balloon",
    "either"
];

$('h1').html(function(_,html) {
    var reg = new RegExp('('+words.join('|')+')','gi');
    return html.replace(reg, '<span class="red">$1</span>', html)
});
```

```css
.red {color : red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>This title contains the word Balloon</h1>
<h1>This title contains the word Oranges</h1>
<h1>This title doesn't contain either of those terms</h1>
```

Comment: can i asked `return html.replace(reg, '<span class="red">$1</span>', html)` where `$1` is from. can you add more explanation thank you

Comment: Again, this is replacing substring, not word. What if you have the word 'string' to replace and your text contains the word 'substring'. I'm not sure what is OP's expected behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff - indeed it is, but that could be solved by adding word boundaries to the regex, if the op needs to match whole words only.

Comment: @adeneo Ya, exactly

Comment: @guradio - the `$*` is "replacement", it remembers the matches in the regex, so you don't have to write them out literally, and acts sorta like a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your element set, like so, and replace it with anything in an array of keywords:

```
<h1>This title contains the word Balloon</h1>
<h1>This title contains the word Oranges</h1>
<h1>This title doesn't contain either of those terms</h1>
<h1>This title contains both Balloon and Oranges</h1>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var wordsToHighlight = ['Balloon', 'Oranges'];
$('h1').each(function() {
  for (var i = 0, l = wordsToHighlight.length; i < l; i++) {
    if ($(this).html().indexOf(wordsToHighlight[i]) !== -1) {
      var newValue = $(this).html().replace(wordsToHighlight[i], 
          '<span>' + wordsToHighlight[i] + '</span>');
      $(this).html(newValue);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's replacing substring not word. I mean it depends OP definition of "word"

Answer (score 0):

While the answers provided here are theoretically correct, they will use `innerHTML` which is evil. It will destroy events and triggers DOM generation over and over again. Also, you'll probably need to remove highlights at a time, so you are reinverting the wheel.

There's a plugin that solves your problem: [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

Usage can be done e.g. the following way:

```js
$(function(){
  // pass an array to highlight or a simple string term
  $("h1").mark(["Balloon", "Oranges"]);
});
```

```css
mark{
  background: orange;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/7.0.0/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>
<h1>This title contains the word Balloon</h1>
<h1>This title contains the word Oranges</h1>
<h1>This title doesn't contain either of those terms</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have an object containing all the words you want wrapped (including another specifications eg class or the tag used) and then just iterate over all fields of the object while using your command that just constructs the string to be used.