# Highlighting a keyword which is entered in a search box in a webpage

Tags: jquery, html

I used this:

```
$('#srch').click(function(){
  var s='';
  s = $('#gt').val();
  if (s == '')
  {
    $("p") .addClass("default");
  } else {
    $("p:contains('"+ s +"')") .addClass("active");
  }
});
```

Its working but it keep on storing the previous data. I want the previous data to be cleared.

Comment: Please see this - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011385/jquery-search-in-static-html-page-with-highlighting-of-found-word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011385/jquery-search-in-static-html-page-with-highlighting-of-found-word)

Comment: Please see this - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011385/jquery-search-in-static-html-page-with-highlighting-of-found-word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011385/jquery-search-in-static-html-page-with-highlighting-of-found-word)

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeClass()` to remove the highlighted element class

```
$('#srch').click(function(){
$("p").removeClass("active"); 
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear input after search just use `$(...).val('')`:

```
$('#srch').click(function(){
    var s='';   
    s = $('#gt').val();
    $('#gt').val('');
    if (s == ''){       
        $("p") .addClass("default");    
    } else{
        $("p:contains('"+ s +"')") .addClass("active"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 $('#srch').on("click",function(){
    var s = $('#gt').val();
    $("p").removeClass("active")
    if (s == ''){       
        $("p").addClass("default");    
    } else{
        $("p:contains('"+ s +"')").addClass("active"); 
    }
});
```

**[Working Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/z0pb2s7d/1/)**

Comment: Thanks! It worked.
But its not working in online server. How to do that?

Comment: Send me online link, will check

Comment: i cant! actually the site is incomplete, its under testing phase. so cant reveal it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ternary operator` you can do this in single line .

```js
$('#srch').click(function(){
    $("p") .removeClass("active") ;
    var s='';   
    s = $('#gt').val();
    s == ''?  $("p") .addClass("default")  : $("p:contains('"+ s +"')") .addClass("active"); 
});
```

```css
.default {
  background: green;
}
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a test contain</p>
<input type='text' id='gt'/>
<input type='button' id='srch'>
```